# How to generate rowspan with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to insert a rowspan after every first td in every table, but I can't.

I started searching and made this code. It doesn't work, but may tell more about thing I need.

```
$("table").each(function(){
    var rowcount = $("tr").length;
    var insert = ('<td rowspan="' + rowcount + '" class="table-rowspan">&nbsp;</td>')
    $("table td:first").after(insert);
});
```

Comment: Hey just a quick question so you have many table and you just want that the first column should add another column with rowspan? right :) just checking before I answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiya please try this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kAzfQ/ **updated demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kAzfQ/3/

Solution will add columns `fooo` after every first td one first row. Demo includes 2 table.

Please let me know if I am missing anything,

Hope this helps,

**Note** You can add row count back I have excluded it for this demo. to show you the `td` append after first row first td. B-)

**code**

```
$('table').each(function() {

    var rowcount = $("tr").length;

    $(this).find('td').eq(0).after('<td rowspan=rowcount class="table-rowspan">==>fooo <== </td>');

});​
```

Comment: Thanks. But it looks that this way creates wrong rowspan number too. Script sum all tr's—from all tables. So it couldn't be useful :-(.

alert(rowcount) shows the sum

Comment: Hiya Yep it does, I re-used the code from your OP :)) see this is this you want gets the first row only: **Another demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/kAzfQ/3/ ; please let me know if this suits you I will update my post and don't forget to accept it as answer. cheers :)

Comment: ('<td rowspan="' + rowcount + '" class="table-rowspan">fooo</td>')
with this syntax it works, thanks :-)